# How can I link a NativeLibrarySpec library specified in a different build.gradle file to my main build.gradle file?

Tags: c++, gradle, build.gradle

Previously I had everything in my main build.gradle file. I would like to break it up and have each component have its own build.gradle file, then include those libraries from the sub-components to the main build file.

Before: build.gradle

```
model.components {
  mainApp(NativeExecutableSpec) {
    sources.cpp.lib library: "lib1", linkage: "static"
    sources.cpp.lib library: "lib2", linkage: "static"
  }
  lib1(NativeExecutableSpec) {
    //defined source set
  }
  lib2(NativeExecutableSpec) {
    //defined source set
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do:

build.gradle

```
model.components {
  mainApp(NativeExecutableSpec) {
    sources.cpp.lib library: ":lib1", linkage: "static"
    sources.cpp.lib library: ":lib2", linkage: "static"
  }
```

settings.gradle

```
include "libFolder"
```

libFolder/build.gradle

```
model.components {
  lib1(NativeExecutableSpec) {
    //defined source set
  }
  lib2(NativeExecutableSpec) {
    //defined source set
  }
}
```

My error now is that the main build.gradle file cannot locate the libraries by the :lib1 name. Can someone tell me what I'm missing or if this is possible?
Thanks in advance!